# Unable to create 64bit msi installer using VS 2010

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, exe, installshield

I want to create a 64 bit msi installer using VS 2010.
I try to create a project by clicking on
Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment->Visual Studio Installer->SetUp Project.

But project does not allow Target platform to be edited, it is blank by default.
I want to create msi installer for 32 as well as 64 bit.

Comment: The question was perfectly clear to anyone who understands Windows Installer technology. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372070(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Setup and Deployment (VDPROJ) projects don't support creating x64 installers.  This is one of the many reasons why Microsoft killed that technology in VS2012.

The replacement tool is InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition and it [does support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/15/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-2013-and-installshield-limited-edition.aspx) 64bit installations.

If you want to stay on VS 2010 then you'd need to consider using InstallShield 2013 Professional and/or [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: I read this somewhere but I'm not sure what I wrote is true now. :(